# Do we need a new diamond moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, election

Recently [election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223009/february-2014-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results) on Stack Overflow was completed, do we need the same here. I think we need so, I'm member for more than one year in DA and I seen very few activity from one diamond [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), I think we need a new diamond moderator.

Comment: Will respond when I get more time, but the average flag handling time is about 7.5 hours on SO.  Our monthly average is at 1.5 right now.

Comment: thanks @MPD with right information:)

Comment: Just to clarify the question here.  Is this asking about whether we need a mod to handle the workload, or do you think the current moderators are slacking off or  doing a bad job.  If it's the later, that would be helpful to know (I mean it).

Comment: @MPD im not talking about workload, only the inactiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking for myself, and not for the other moderators, I don't think we need another diamond (ie, elected) moderator.

Diamond moderators are essentially [the janitors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) around here.  I do think we need to continue, and expand, our [community moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) of the site.

As a point of reference, I read that that average flag handling time on the main Stack Exchange site was a little over 7 hours.  Our average is about 1.5 hour right now, and was about 1 hour for a long time.  I normally handle 3-10 a day.

SO gets lots of crap questions/answers, but also a lot of trolls, idiots, and other user related problems.  Those flags take time to deal with.

Most of our flags are rather easy to deal with, though we are getting more flags on marginal content (eg, poor answers, but still an attempt to answer).  I will often take a look at these, and wait for a bit before making a decision.  I also let some of these sit to let the [10k users review them](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), too.

I don't know why our fourth moderator hasn't been visiting much, but I think he is a very valuable asset to the community here and wish he would participate more.

Comment: There are only 6 of us 10k users without a diamond, and it seems we're from various timezones, so our flag review can't be fast. How many NAA / VLQ flags we need to get an effect?

Comment: @Mołot Not really sure.  I would guess that 75% of the NAA flags are definitely correct.  The rest tend to be link-only answers with flags.  Those are mostly easy to deal with.  The VLQ and QVLQ ones are tougher.  Editing *could* salvage a lot of them, so I will typically mark as helpful, but not delete.

Comment: Do you have an idea how the stats you mentioned in your answer look like today (about 3 years later)? If so maybe you can add an update to your answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The average flag handling time on DA is currently **17 minutes**.  Don't have recent network stats.  And, the mods will periodically let some flags sit (sometimes up to a day) when they are weird or we want everyone to see something has happened.  I'm handling the same amount as I normally do.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that one of the mods is less active may mean he should retire. But it does not mean we need new moderators. Unless you can show how moderation tasks are not done fast enough, we don't need an election.

I think current team is fast enough, and even when I don't agree with them, I can't say they can not keep up with their tasks.

Of course if you will ever meant to give actual diamonds to us, I'll gladly accept ;)

[image]

Comment: I can echo this - the amount of stuff we actually need to handle is very low, 3 of us can easily cover it (at the moment at least)

Comment: @Clive i'm not ask for more mod, talking about replacement & if 3 mod is enough then its fine :)

Comment: @Bala but there are 3 active mods and that's enough, right? So there is no need to look for new one, no matter if he would replace inactive one, or be added to the team. Unless you see some moderation problems I (and Clive, apparently) do not?

Comment: molot instead of inactive mod, honestly i consider you as the replacement. :) suppose if you participate.

Comment: @Bala no, thank you, I'm too much strict, angry, clingy and impatient.

Comment: @Bala Yeah I personally think 3 is enough at the moment. Not opposed to new moderators at all though, so if others feel differently we'll act on it